# How do I prevent file naming restarts on Nikon D5300?

Tags: nikon-d5300

If I take a set of images and remove them from the card, the next batch will start again at DSC_0001. I would like when I empty my card my camera to continue from the last number that has been taken of my last photo. (For example I have 300 photos and I move them to my pc, when I take a new photo I would like it to be 301 and increased from where it has ended)

Is there a way to keep the numbers from resetting when the images are removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From page 188 of the [D5300 Reference Manual](http://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/25/D5300.html)

Menu > Custom settings > d4: File Number Sequence > On.

[image]